# Swagger UI failing to load API definition in Red Hat 8.5

Tags: jersey, swagger-ui, openapi, redhat

I am new to Swagger UI. I have added the Swagger dependency in my `pom.xml` and am able to see Swagger UI on a Windows machine without any error. But when I deploy the same application in Red Hat 8.5, I am getting the "failed to load API definition" error with a "404 not found" exception.

Here is my error screenshot:

[image]

I have checked the configuration file path on the Red Hat machine, it is in the correct location only.

My openapi-configuration file is:

```json
{
   "prettyPrint":true,
   "cacheTTL":0,
   
   "openAPI":{
      "info":{
         "version":"1.0",
         "title":"APP Name",
         "description":"REST API Documentaiton"
      },
        "servers": [
            {
                "url": "/{contextpath}/api/",
                "variables": {
                    "contextpath": {
                        "default": "applicationContextPath",
                        "description": "Provide the application context path here"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
      "components": {
            "securitySchemes":{
                "BasicAuth":{
                     "type": "http",
                     "scheme": "basic"
                },
                "ApiKeyAuth": {
                    "type": "apiKey",
                    "in": "header",
                    "name": "Authorization",
                    "required": true
                }
            }
      },
      "security":[
        {
            "BasicAuth":  [],
            "ApiKeyAuth": []
        }
        ]
   }
  
}
```